# Html responsive image map in wordpress

Tags: html, dictionary, responsive

I have a problem with responsive image's map. I have inserted all percentile value, but when I open article wordpress the links appear in all page (not only in image).
This is url of problem: https://www.jaiss.it/carmignano/2020/03/17/prodotti-tipici-di-carmignano/
And this the code:

```
<img src="https://www.image-maps.com/m/private/0/eq4hfs8hr5cbgghl16ob5c28up_fattorie-carmignano.jpg" usemap="#imm" width="100%">
<map name="imm">
<a href="castelvecchio" title="Castelvecchio" style="position: absolute; left: 24.1%; top: 2.8%; width: 31%; height: 36%; z-index: 2;"></a>
<a href="artimino" title="Tenuta di Artimino" style="position: absolute; left: 0.4%; top: 1.8%; width: 22.1%; height: 21.2%; z-index: 2;"></a>
<a href="capezzana" title="Capezzana" style="position: absolute; left: 2.3%; top: 26.2%; width: 18%; height: 36%; z-index: 2;"></a><a href="sassolo" title="Il Sassolo" style="position: absolute; left: 58.8%; top: 6.6%; width: 14.5%; height: 28.4%; z-index: 2;"></a>
<a href="piaggia" title="Piaggia" style="position: absolute; left: 79.9%; top: 5%; width: 13.2%; height: 36%; z-index: 2;"></a><a href="pierazzuoli" title="Tenute Pierazzuoli" style="position: absolute; left: 33.6%; top: 62.8%; width: 21.3%; height: 36%; z-index: 2;"></a>
<a href="allocco" title="Podere Allocco" style="position: absolute; left: 80.6%; top: 53.6%; width: 17.6%; height: 41%; z-index: 2;"></a>
<a href="ambra" title="Fattoria Ambra" style="position: absolute; left: 24.1%; top: 39.8%; width: 30.2%; height: 20.2%; z-index: 2;"></a>
<a href="sanbiagio" title="Colline San Biagio" style="position: absolute; left: 1.4%; top: 67.4%; width: 30.2%; height: 29.6%; z-index: 2;"></a>
<a href="borriana" title="Tenuta La Borriana" style="position: absolute; left: 57.5%; top: 36.4%; width: 22.1%; height: 33.2%; z-index: 2;"></a>
<a href="pratesi" title="Pratesi" style="position: absolute; left: 55.9%; top: 75.6%; width: 24.2%; height: 22.4%; z-index: 2;"></a>
</map>
```

Anyone can help me to solve issues?

Answer (score 0):

This is a late answer, but I recently also had the challenge of creating a responsive image map in WordPress.

A simple solution that works: install the "WP Draw Attention" WordPress plugin and create your image map using that solution.

You can simply upload your image, create selection fields which can be clicked and choose URLs for each field. Then you insert the image map into any page you want using the plugin's shortcode. Only in the image on pages you put the shortcode the clickable links will be active.

Here's a How To guide on setting it up: https://torquemag.io/2021/03/how-to-create-a-wordpress-image-map-and-why-you-should/

Cheers,

Joris

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).